# Unsupported operation on virtual geometry while extruding 2D geometry to 3D geometry in COMSOL 5.2a

Tags: comsol

I have created a 2D waveguide system, and now I've realized that I need to modify the height of the waveguide as well. To achieve this, I attempted to extrude the existing 2D system into a 3D shape. However, I encountered an error message stating that the operation on virtual geometry is not supported. I'm seeking a solution to this issue. Any suggestions or advice would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

I use extude in built feature to make it 3D, but could not convert into 3D.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is add a work plane in Geometry and then create or import your 2D waveguide system in that plane and then extrude from the plane. I hope it will work. Thank you